# Search and replace a pattern with new line except for a pattern

Tags: substitute, formatting

I am having a very long line file, I have to break the line into number of small lines.

Example:

```
< this>is a testing< /this>< next>testing< /next>< tested>successfully< /tested>
```

I have to break it into as of below

```
< this>is a testing< / this> 

< next>testing< / next> 

< tested>successfully< /tested>
```

for this I am trying to search for `<` and add new line, but this results in:

```
< this>is a testing

< /this>

< next>testing

< /next>

< tested>successfully

< /tested>
```

What would be the correct command to fix this?

Comment: What you are looking for is not a simple search and replace it is a way to format some html or xml which is much more complex and has much more edge cases than you might think. To do this I would recommend using a specialized tool (there are plenty like [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pretty) or [this](https://pypi.org/project/xmlformatter/)) it will be much easier and more efficient than crafting your own regex. And you can even use `equalprg` to use these tools directly within vim (see [`:h 'equalprg'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27equalprg%27))

Comment: Not exactly what you are looking for, but I prefer this: `%s#<\(/\w\+>\|\w\+/>\)\zs#\r#g`, which will add a linebreak after each closing tag.

Comment: Check this out http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Cleanup_your_HTML

Answer (score 1):

If for some reason you can't check those tools that statox recommended, you can use something like this:

```
%s;\(< */[^>]\+>\);\1^M;g
```

It will look at every line for every closing tag (`\(< */[^>]\+>\)`) and replace it by itself and then a new line.

The first part (to identify the closing tag) will search for

- a `<` character
- followed by any number of spaces ( `*`),
- then a slash (`/`)
- and any (positive) number of any character different from a closing tag sign (`[^>]\+`)
- and finally a close tag sign (`>`).

To insert a new line (`^M` above) you should press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Q</kbd> if you are on on Windows) and then press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Comment: This can be simplified to `:%s;< */[^>]\+>;&\r;g` – do you have `very magic` set as default? With the default `magic` setting, `(`, `)` and `+` need to be escaped, see `:h magic`.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to find all `><` patterns and to insert two new lines.

One of the simplest is to do

```
:s/></>\r\r</g
```

Or

```
:s/>\zs\ze</\r\r/g
```

Comment: But what if there’s an empty one like `< that>< / that>`?

Comment: Ha, I only considered the case in the OP.